# Can i use a variable outside Subscribe in function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, function, variables

I have an array of items that I want to use **outside** the function
What I want how I can persist the data in the carTypeTemp in the outside console log

```
class CarType {    

 carTypeTemp;

 constructor() {}

 onCellValueChanged: (data: any) => {
            this._typeslisteService.getListeFromTypeListe('Car Type')
              .subscribe((liste: Liste[]) => {
                 this.carTypeTemp = liste;
                console.log('inside', this.carTypeTemp );
              }, throwError);

           console.log('outside',  this.carTypeTemp );
    },
}
```

Comment: this.carTypeTemp = liste; it's inside subscribe a async task , (so your outside console log is printed first) and when later on subscribe call work , then data is set and u can see  inside console log with value , after then you can access this.carTypeTemp  ,  you will get value all the places

Comment: Yes anytime you see a subscribe anywhere in your code, you have to consider any and all statements after that subscribe (time wise).  Just a general rule.  This article shows how to turn an observable with subscription into an await-able construct.  Which means no code below the subscription occurs until the return from the subscribe completes. https://dev.to/jwp/observable-to-promise-for-async-await-2d9c

Comment: @JohnPeters thx bro 